# How to pass the system time to the Metal fragment function?

Tags: scenekit, metal

I am using SceneKit and SCNProgram to modify an object in the game scene, and I would like to get access to the system time in my fragment function in .metal file. I guess the way is to pass the time data from the SceneKit but it’s not quite clear for me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SCNSceneBuffer` structure has a `time` property (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram)). This page also mentions ways to pass custom data from the CPU to a custom program, if you need to.